# Converting a Resque queue to SideKiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque, sidekiq

I am trying to convert a Resque queue to Sidekiq. I've completed the entire setup for Sidekiq, and now am ready to add all my resque jobs to sidekiq ones.

My question is: Can I simply rename all the resque keys in redis to the corresponding sidekiq keys?

For instance, if I have a queue named "twitter", the redis key for resque is "resque:queue:twitter", but the key in sidekiq would be "queue:twitter". Could I simply rename "resque:queue:twitter" to "queue:twitter" ?

Comment: +1 becoz I dont feel there is renaming key api in `redis` list Looking forward if some one can prove me wrong

Comment: Why wouldn't you just let your existing Resque workers flush out their existing queues, and let Sidekiq handle any new jobs? Manually moving jobs over shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @ChrisHeald because doing so would require waiting for a long long time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok Finally Got it

There are few global command that I missed and `rename` is perhaps one of them.

Where you can rename the keys If you want

do something like this

```
redis.rename "resque:queue:twitter","queue:twitter"
```

And see if it work

Cheers

Thanks for the question It just brushed up by redis knowledge

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code I used to migrate over our existing resque jobs to sidekiq.  You can use this in the rails console.

```
['low', 'high', 'critical'].each do |queue|
  p [1, queue]
  old_queue = "resque:queue:#{queue}"
  new_queue = "queue:#{queue}"
  # $redis.ltrim new_queue, 0, 0 # can optionally clear out new queue, in case of multiple runs

  vals = $redis.lrange(old_queue, 0, -1)
  p [2, queue]
  $redis.pipelined do
    vals.each do |val|
      $redis.lpush(new_queue, val)
    end
  end
end
```

You can also just set:

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { :namespace => 'resque' }
end
Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { :namespace => 'resque' }
end
```

and it will work out of the box.  But after I deployed without this, I had pending jobs in both formats, so had to use the first code I pasted to migrate things over.